# Python Pandas: Counting the amount of subsequent value and assign a name if conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

For example I have created this data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Cycle': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                             2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
                             4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]})


#Maybe something like this: df['Cycle Type'] = df['Cycle'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: len(set(x)) != len(x),raw= True).replace({0 : False, 1: True})
```

I want to count the amount of values and than assign a type of cycle to it. If the cycle has less than 12 rows or more than 100 rows mark it as bad, else mark it as good. I was thinking of using something like that lambda function to check if the value from the row before was the same, but I'm not sure how to add the count feature to give it the parameters I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by counting the number of rows in each group with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`pandas.DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html), and [`pandas.DataFrame.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) as

```
df["cycle_quality"] = df.groupby("Cycle")["Cycle"].transform("count")
```

Then apply the quality function to it using [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

• If number of rows is less than 12 and more than 100, define `cycle_quality` as `bad`

• Else, `cycle_quality` should be `good`

```
df["cycle_quality"] = df.apply(lambda x: "bad" if x["cycle_quality"] < 12 or x["cycle_quality"] > 100 else "good", axis=1)

[Out]:
    Cycle cycle_quality
0       0          good
1       0          good
2       0          good
3       0          good
4       0          good
..    ...           ...
71      5           bad
72      5           bad
73      5           bad
74      5           bad
75      5           bad
```

Comment: I m pretty sure between is faster than apply especially when data gets bigger.

Comment: @SomeDude: no competition there. I just ran a `timeit` on each method. Changed the values to `np.repeat([*range(100)],100)` and ran `1000` loops. [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73531225/18470692) by @GoncaloPeres took 107.939 sec, [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73531339/18470692) by @SomeDude took 1.084 sec, and [answer3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73531467/18470692) took 1.069 sec. Performance is in fact already noticeable on the current example (almost factor 2).

Comment: @ouroboros1 as Donald Knuth said "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". Working solutions/shipping code comes before optimizations. But glad you (answer 3) and others (there are already 4 answers to this question), managed to come up with other alternatives and shared it: the whole community benefits from this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to get size of each cycle and use [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) to see if the size of each cycle falls between 13, 100 (both inclusive) and mark the True as good and False as bad. Because as per requirement any size that is less than 12 and greater than 100 is bad and everything else that is in between [13, 100] is good.

```
df['Cycle_Type'] = df.groupby('Cycle')['Cycle'].transform('size').between(13, 100,
        inclusive='both').replace({True: 'good', False: 'bad'})
```

output:

```
    Cycle Cycle_Type
0       0        bad
1       0        bad
2       0        bad
3       0        bad
4       0        bad
..    ...        ...
71      5        bad
72      5        bad
73      5        bad
74      5        bad
75      5        bad
```

Edit:

You can change the interval in which you want good or bad as you wish.
If your requirement is that less than 12 should be marked good then include 12 in the interval like:

```
df['Cycle_Type'] = df.groupby('Cycle')['Cycle'].transform('size').between(12, 100,
            inclusive='both').replace({True: 'good', False: 'bad'})
```

Then your output is:

```
    Cycle Cycle_Type
0       0       good
1       0       good
2       0       good
3       0       good
4       0       good
..    ...        ...
71      5        bad
72      5        bad
73      5        bad
74      5        bad
75      5        bad
```

Comment: @SeanK22 `0` should be `good`, as it has 12 rows, and not `bad` as the answer output shows.

Comment: @SeanK22 I edited answer to accommodate GoncaloPeres's comment. Its actually flexible to just change boundaries of your interval.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve this:

- Use [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get a count for all unique values in `df['Cycle']`.
- Next, apply [`pd.Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) to obtain a series with booleans.
- This series we turn into `'good'|'bad'` with `replace`, before passing it to [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) applied to column `Cycle`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Cycle': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]})

vc = df.Cycle.value_counts()

df['Cycle_Type'] = df['Cycle'].map(
    vc.between(12,100,inclusive='both').replace({True: 'good', False: 'bad'}))

# printing output per value
print(df.groupby('Cycle', as_index=False).first())

   Cycle Cycle_Type
0      0       good
1      1        bad
2      2       good
3      3       good
4      4       good
5      5        bad
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `pd.cut()`. This could be useful if more categories than good and bad need to be applied.

```
(df['Cycle']
.map(
    pd.cut(df['Cycle'].value_counts(),
    bins = [0,12,100,np.inf],
    right = False,
    labels = ['bad','good','bad'],
    ordered=False)))
```

or

```
s = df['Cycle'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
np.where(s.groupby(s).transform('count').between(12,100),'good','bad')
```

Output:

```
0     good
1     good
2     good
3     good
4     good
      ... 
71     bad
72     bad
73     bad
74     bad
75     bad
```

Comment: Very nice. And at comparable speed.